# Skipping / jumping drop anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a drop anchor that links from a down arrow at the bottom of a full-page parallax image to another section on the page. Drop anchor:

```
<section id="first" class="big-image parallax lander" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wagstaffsandbx.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Homepage-Photo-1.jpg&quot;); background-position: 50% -7.2px;" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.2" data-stellar-vertical-offset="50">

    <a href="#welcome" class="arrow"><img class="down-arrow" src="https://wagstaffsandbx.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/down-arrow.png" alt="down-arrow"></a>

</section>
```

Where it goes:

```
<section id="welcome" class="text-block"><h1>welcome</h1><p>Pitchfork mumblecore stumptown, intelligentsia wolf put a bird on it man bun wayfarers organic actually sartorial. Sriracha disrupt kickstarter fingerstache selvage pour-over. Paleo ugh lumbersexual, kinfolk banjo banh mi meditation cliche 3 wolf moon single-origin coffee viral blog polaroid pop-up.</p>
</section>
```

Clicking on the arrow works, but the smooth scroll to the drop anchor takes place, it scrolls to the right place and then shifts downward for no apparent reason.

Here's the jQuery that I'm using to implement the smooth scrolling. You'll see there's an offset for the navigation of 140px:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a.arrow").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top -140
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>
```

You can see the issue in action here: https://wagstaffsandbx.wpengine.com/test-stellar/

UN to see site: demo
PW to see site: password

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by this:

```
    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
```

As changing `location` this way triggers the corresponding reaction from the browser.

Suggest replacing it with the following:

```
if (typeof (history.pushState) !== 'undefined') {
    var obj = {title: $('head title').text(), URL: hash};
    history.pushState(obj, obj.title, obj.URL);
}
```

Comment: This works. Thank you! I'm still learning Javascript. Would you be able to explain what the code snippet you provided does? I'd love to understand why it works.

Comment: Please consider the article here: https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/